# run rscript from command line until it succeeds

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I need to run an `R script` from `command prompt` in `windows`. The problem is that the `R script` has some lines which sometimes gives `warnings/errors` (not any logical or syntax error but just fails due to data issue. Anyway, this is not important). So, instead of re-running it manually every time it fails, I want to put the `system command` in some kind of loop to run it until it succeeds i.e. does not return any `warnings/errors`.

I am using the following system command to run the r script in question.

```
Rscript D:/r_code.r 123 544 

# 123 and 544 are two numeric arguments which I pass to the r script.
```

How do I do I achieve my task?

NOTE: In the end, I need to run a batch file which will have multiple commands to run different R scripts and I need to put this loop until it succeeds over every command in it. Batch file will look like:

```
Rscript D:/r_code1.r 123 544        # put loop condition here
Rscript D:/r_code2.r 125 524        # put loop condition here
Rscript D:/r_code3.r 156 553        # put loop condition here
Rscript D:/r_code4.r 187 587        # put loop condition here
```

**Adding a screenshot showing how error or warning gets displayed in command prompt as soon as I run the rscript command**

[image]

Comment: Are the errors from the script outputted back to the commandline when run from it? Could you give an example of the errors/warnings it gives?

Comment: @DennisvanGils I have added a screenshot showing how error or warning gets displayed in command prompt as soon as I run the rscript command.

Comment: Does the R script return a non-zero exit code upon failure? you can find out by opening a new command prompt window, calling the R script from there and then executing 'echo %ErrorLevel%` (this displays the exit code)...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
@echo off
:loop
Rscript D:/r_code.r 123 544 | findstr "exception error warning" >nul 2>nul
set warningfound=%errorlevel%
if %warningfound% neq 1 goto loop
```

This executes a command, and if it finds one of the words in the findstr command in the output it goes to the loop tag, and executes it again.

Comment: I tried it, but the script ran only once, did not iterate.

Comment: I think you reversed the logic... you don't need the variable `warning found`... and I'd put `2>&1` before the `Rscript` call just in case the warnings are output at _STDERR_...

Comment: I tried `:Loop
Rscript D:/check.r 2 3 | find "Warning Error"
if not %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :Loop
echo Connection established`, it worked. Thanks for giving me a direction. By the way, is there any way to write this syntax in one line in some way? @aschipfl

Comment: To execute a command conditionally if the preceeding one succeeded (zero exit code), use `&&`; for the case it failed (non-zero exit code), use `||`; for instance: `command && echo Success. || echo Failure.`; I hope the helps...